# jQuery Main Navigation Issues

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation

I am having issues with my "hover off" function. For the most part the complete function works. I can hover the `<li>` to reveal the underlying `<ul>` as desired. The issue comes when the user hovers off the `<li>` to select the child `<ul>` and the links. As you can see the "hover out" function kicks in and negates the fact that the child `<ul>` is within the parent `<li>`

[example of the issue: If you hover over the li and try to selecet the sub menu](http://amigojuan.com/pushstart/)

I have tried multiple CSS positioning and styles and have arrived here:

```
nav {
   width:100%;
   height:50px;
   background:url(../assets/navBG.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
   position:relative;
   z-index:999;
}

ul.nav {
   list-style:none;
   position:absolute;
}

ul.nav li {
   float:left;
   font-family: 'PlayRegular';
   font-size:18px;
   color:#fff;
   padding:13px 43px;
   background:url(../assets/navIcon.png) center right no-repeat;
   cursor:pointer;
}

ul.nav li > ul {
   position:absolute;
   display:none;
   list-style:none;
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   top:50px;
   left:0;
   overflow:hidden;
   background:#000;
 }
```

I have worked with the Jquery to slideDown the child ul but cannot find a way to allow it to be "hover-able"

```
$("ul.nav li").hover( function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "linear",
        queue: false        
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideUp({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "linear",
        queue: false    
    });
});
```

Am I missing something to allow the child `<ul>` to be considered part of the parent `<li>`? is it a Jquery or CSS issue? I know it is not an HTML issue because i am 100% sure I have written it semantically correct with no open `<divs>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scripts working fine here, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/4RxGf/1/

In this demo, jquery lib is v1.9.1, test your site with this version?

```
$("ul.nav li").hover( function() {
    $(this).stop().find("ul").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "linear",
        queue: false        
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().find("ul").slideUp({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "linear",
        queue: false    
    });
});
```

Comment: Alright the .stop() function worked perfectly exactly what I needed to to do. Thank you very much, I will remember that now for the future.